# Problem with WCF client calling one-way operation

Tags: wcf, soap, sap-pi, sap-xi

I have run into a problem when calling web service on a SAP PI bus from my WCF client.
The operation is defined as one-way, and the method on my proxy operation contract is decorated accordingly when the service reference is added.
However, the service client gets an exception when calling the according operation:

***The one-way operation returned a non-null message with Action=''***

Using SoapUI, the method on the bus can be called successfully, and it returns a SOAP envelope with an empty body. The bus people told me, this is according to the SOAP specs:

---

(SOAP specs, chapter 4.7.9, One-way operations):

There are differing interpretations of how HTTP is to be used when performing one-way operations.

**R2714** For one-way operations, an INSTANCE MUST NOT return a HTTP response that contains an envelope. Specifically, the HTTP response entity-body must be empty.

**R2750** A CONSUMER MUST ignore an envelope carried in a HTTP response message in a one-way operation.

**R2727** For one-way operations, a CONSUMER MUST NOT interpret a successful HTTP response status code (i.e., 2xx) to mean the message is valid or that the receiver would process it.

---

So it seems, my WCF client doesn't comply with R2750.

I have found out that when I force the operation contract on the proxy to be *IsOneWay = false*, everything works.

Is there anything wrong with the way WCF handles one way operations or do I do something wrong (more likely)? 
Is there anything else I should do, it just doesn't seem right to override the generated WCF proxy client.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Great question +1.  I'd argue their side does not comply with R2714 either.  Please consider filing an incident with Microsoft and letting us know what the result is.

Comment: Similar question (and more info): http://stackoverflow.com/q/4510484/46039

Comment: Link to SOAP spec 4.7.9 One-way operations: http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like SAP PI incorrectly sends an empty SOAP envelope and .NET incorrectly interprets that envelope.

Some options from [this thread](http://www.go4answers.com/Example/exception-while-making-way-call-wcf-56416.aspx):

- alter the generated proxy and remove OneWay=true (or add OneWay=false) to the method definition
- catch the Protocol Violation in an exception handler and ignore it
- use a 2.0 style webreference to call the service
- apply SAP patch [Note 1459995 - Soap Sender Adapter HTTP 202](http://www.stechno.net/sap-notes.html?view=sapnote&id=1459995) and add &responsecode202=true to the url

The first and last options both worked for me. Further discussion on this [sap.com thread](http://scn.sap.com/message/9031931).

Comment: Thanks for this, it's still relevant for me.

Comment: I think that from a system perspective a web service call should always reply back with a confirmation. True or false,  1 or 0 to indicate your message was received and processed from the other side.

Comment: Last option worked for me with SAP PI 7.3.1 and .NET 4.7.2

Answer (score 4):

I would take a look at this article as well by Gerben van Loon [here](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/gerben/archive/2010/02/01/wcf-best-practice-5-one-way-is-not-always-really-one-way.aspx).  One way operation might not really be one way according to the standards.

Comment: The semantics of oneway web calls over `SOAP` are comparable to `void()` not fire-and forget. Just like a method that returns `void()` the invocation is blocking and does have the capability of "returning" an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Check this SAP thread out for the complete discussion:
http://scn.sap.com/thread/1627368

@Brian Low has answered this question correctly and very thoroughly (is should get marked as the answer).

I would also like to add that this is a known error in which the SOAP Adapter does not comply with the aforementioned WS-I Basic Profile 1.1 (R2750) and WCF does not comply with (R2750). The result... Hours of wasted time and teeth gnashing....

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this particular problem can be fixed by adding the following attribute declaration to the operation in the client porxy:

`[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However adding this to the generated client proxy is about the same as setting the OneWay property to false. And unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what the signature of the method looks like, my best guess is that your method defined to return something other than "void".  Since the operation is one-way, the method can only be defined using "void" (has no return).  Anything else, and the operation is NOT one-way.

Comment: The method actually returns void