# WCF IsOneWay=true causing problems

Tags: wcf

I have written a one-way service in php that contains one method with `OperationContract( IsOneWay=true)`

When I call this method from my .net client application then it gives me an error

> The one-way operation returned a
>   non-null message with Action=''

Here is my proxy generated method :

```
 [OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay = true, Action = "http://192.168.1.5/zfsapi/api.php#terminateProcess")]
 [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults=true, Use=OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
 [ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(ZfsSnapshot))]
 void terminateProcess(int pid);
```

Can anyone tell me why this error occur and solution on this?

Comment: Those links might help you: - http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2010/08/one-way-operation-returned-non-null.html - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643241/problem-with-wcf-client-calling-one-way-operation

Comment: Similar question (and some answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643241/problem-with-wcf-client-calling-one-way-operation/14860472#14860472